# Haskell Error when using readsPrec -> Could not match type

Tags: haskell, types, input, instance

I tried several hours from now to implement a custom read function for this data structure:

```
data Term = Monom(Float, Integer)
        | Addition(Term, Term) 
        | Subtraktion(Term, Term)
        | Multiplikation(Term, Term) 
        | Division(Term, Term)
```

The idea behind the read function is to parse infix-terms like `(+ (+ Monom Monom) Monom)`. For now I tried Monoms which are numbers like `2` which translate to `Monom(2,0)`, not expressions like `2x^5` which would translate to `Monom(2,5)`.

```
instance Read Term where 
    readsPrec _ inp = let [(a,b)] = lex inp in
        case a of
        -- these are control characters for making the input look nicer
        "(" -> readsPrec 0 b
        ")" -> readsPrec 0 b
        " " -> readsPrec 0 b
        -- end character -> nothing to do here
        ""  -> []
        -- operators
        "+" -> let res = readsPrec 0 b in [Addition(res)]  
        "-" -> let res = readsPrec 0 b in [Subtraktion(res)]
        "*" -> let res = readsPrec 0 b in [Multiplikation(res)]
        "/" -> let res = readsPrec 0 b in [Division(res)]
        -- monom
        c -> let res  = readsPrec 0 b in [Monom(read c::Float,0),res]
```

Sadly this does not work, due to this error (which occurs in the Addition and other Operators):

```
Couldn't match expected type `(Term, String)'
            with actual type `Term'
In the return type of a call of `Addition'
In the expression: Addition (res)
In the expression: [Addition (res)]
```

Can you please give hints how fix the source? I have no Idea why the expected type is `(Term,String)` and how to fix it in a appropriate way.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

`readsPrec` for `Term` should return `[(Term, String)]`. So where you return `[Addition (res)]`, you need `[(Term, String)]` but actually have a `[Term]`. Note that the arguments are also wrong: `res` is a `[(Term, String)]`, but in `Addition(res)` you need it to be `(Term, Term)`, so you'll need to fix it later.

Comment: Thanks for the hint - do you have a quick hint on how to fix that? I really have no clue.